# How to delete ONLY the selected post?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

A part of my PHP code is only deleting the first one "post" on SQL instead of the selected one:

```
if (isset ($_POST['delete'])){
        $result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM posts") or die(mysql_error());
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        mysql_query ("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = $data[id]");
        header("Location: main.php");
    };
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your code has some strange things in it. `id` is no variable or value. You are using `$result[id]` in your second query, which should not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step by step, this is what you are doing aka why this is happening:

1) check if post variable delete is set:

```
if (isset ($_POST['delete'])){
```

2) fetch all posts from database:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM posts") or die(mysql_error());
```

3) fetch the first item out of the $result array

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

4) delete the item we just fetched

```
mysql_query ("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = $data[id]");
```

5) redirect to main.php

```
header("Location: main.php");
```

Comment: I've understanded that my problem in on step 3 but how can i fix it?
just started to learn php in a few days, sry for being so noob :DD

Comment: your problem is ultimately that you don't need anything but step 1 and step 4. you should know the id you are deleting, and only need to run that statement. no reason to apologize :p

Comment: ok thanks so much for help and explaining, i've finaly did it :D